# Como ler os três primeiros caracteres de uma string?

Tags: c

Tenho uma aplicação em C. Ela já abre um arquivo texto e lê toda a única linha que o arquivo possui.
É uma linha longa, por exemplo: HTJxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...

Consigo armazenar numa variável esse conteúdo do arquivo texto.

Mas como faço para ler os primeiros três caracteres apenas?

Preciso ler apenas os três primeiros para criar uma condição que os compara com outros valores.

Em Javascript seria algo como:

```
if(linha.substr(0, 2) === "HTJ") 
{
    // Condição
}
```

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer assim:

```
char *minhastring = "HTJxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // string lida no arquivo
char tres_primeiros[4]; // três caracteres mais o terminador de linha
// copia os três primeiros caracteres de um array para o outro
memcpy( tres_primeiros, &minhastring[0], 3); 
tres_primeiros[3] = '\0'; // adiciona o terminador de linha
printf("%s", tres_primeiros); // imprime
```

Veja funcionando [aqui](http://ideone.com/fSDmna).

Answer (score 1):

Pela sua pergunta, acredito que a sua intenção seja apenas fazer a comparação no if e para este caso você pode usar a função strncmp. Então a comparação ficaria assim:

```
if(strncmp(linha, "HTJ", 3))
{
    // Condição
}
```

Mas se você precisa armazenar os 3 primeiros caracteres em uma variável, então a resposta de @MarcusVinicius está perfeita.

Answer (score 0):

Se definires o array que vai guardar a string lida do ficheiro com espaco para apenas 3 caracteres mais o terminador, a funcao `fgets()` faz isso automagicamente:

```
char principio[4];
//char resto[1000];
if (!fgets(principio, sizeof principio, ficheiro)) /* erro */;
//if (!fgets(resto, sizeof resto, ficheiro)) /* erro */;
```